# Showing blank page in backend then up new module to server in Magento

Tags: magento

anyone help me this promblem?
I just create2 Module :ReviewDesign and RatingDesign, structure and code same same Review and Rating in magento, i only change all name  files and content in files become difference name, ex: Review -> Reviewdesign, Rating ->Ratingdesign... That is ok, when I give to localhost, but that isnot ok, when I up to 2 module to server. Log in Admin, showing logo and corner right, log in - logout ..., menu and content below is blank. i dont know why? so very very helper!
Thanks you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Watch your letter Casing. HTML **IS** case sensitive, so reviewDesign is not the same as reviewdesign.